# Detailed guide on how to setup google OAuth in django?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am learning django and setting up a website which does the following.

1. Show google OAuth page
2. Get access token (and mail id) and check whether a user is previously logged in using this google account by searching through database.
3. If previously registered,fetch his details and show them
4. If user logs in for the first time,then show a page to enter some info.
5. Setup cookies or something similar in user's browser to avoid logging in everytime he visits the side(Unless user deletes cookies,etc)
6. Logout option

I went through many tutorials.None of them explain the above 3,4,5 points.Is there an example tutorial (or a series of tutorials) or a sample project which explains all the above steps?
I need something which covers everything.
[This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/django-authentication-with-facebook-instagram-and-linkedin) tutorial comes close but there is no guidance on how to do 3,4,5.(This tutorial uses fb,instagram logins)

Any link or guidance is much appreciated.Thanks for answering.

Comment: If you want to build it yourself you should check the official documentation. Otherwise, there is the allauth package that helps you to integrate different auth providers: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth

Comment: Google OAuth is very easy to implement. A quick Google search shows lots of articles. What you have tried? Stack Overflow is a programming site. Edit your question to show what you have done in software, what errors or problems you have. Read this link to stay on topic for Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask